# Eshell - enable type text in any place

Tags: eshell

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10 (64 bit)

```
M-x eshell
```

Here result:

[image]

But it's read only. But I need to type text in any place in any place in `eshell`.

Also I want to move cursor in any place in eshell buffer. 
All of this I can do in **shell** buffer, but can't in **eshell** buffer. Also I want to **change** text in any place in `eshell` buffer.

Comment: I can do this with eshell on Emacs 27.0.50 on Linux. Can you try this with `emacs -Q`? Also, can you tell us what operating system you are using? It looks like it's Windows, that might matter.

Comment: also, how are you trying to move your cursor? The arrow keys won't work, but `C-n` and `C-p` should.

Comment: @Tyler I updated my post

Comment: @Tyler By C-n and C-p work but it not comfortable. By arrows is better. But with arrows not work in eshell. But in shell buffer work with arrows.

Comment: Hm, did you actually read my answer? I answered all those questions. With my proposed hook you can use the cursor keys and `remove-text-properties-interactive` does allow you to edit the prompt strings in the Eshell buffer even if I strongly advised against it. It can be even more catastrophic to edit the prompt strings in the other shell modes. But, if you must...

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the bindings for the cursor keys in `eshell-mode` with the following Elisp snippet in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

```el
(defun my-eshell-config ()
  "My Eshell configuration."
  (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "<up>") nil)
  (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "<down>") nil))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook #'my-eshell-config)
```

Only the prompt echoes are read-only in `eshell-mode`. All other output of Eshell and your input are editable.

You should never change the prompt echoes -- especially not the last one -- since they are regexp-matched by eshell.

See the doc-string of `eshell-prompt-regexp`:

> A regexp which fully matches your eshell prompt.
>   This setting is important, since it affects how eshell will interpret
>   the lines that are passed to it.
>   If this variable is changed, all Eshell buffers must be exited and
>   re-entered for it to take effect.

If you occasionally want to modify a prompt echo in spite of good advice, you can  use the following command to remove the read-only property from the prompt:

```el
(defun remove-text-properties-interactive (&optional beg end ignore-read-only)
  "Remove text properties in region from BEG to END.
The read-only text property within that region is ignored
if IGNORE-READ-ONLY is non-nil."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (with-silent-modifications
    (let ((inhibit-read-only (if ignore-read-only t inhibit-read-only)))
      (set-text-properties beg end nil))))
```

Since library developers almost always have their good reason to set the `read-only` text property on stretches of buffer text the removal of the `read-only` text property must be enforced by the prefix argument <kbd>C-u</kbd>.
The steps in detail:

1. Mark the region with the Eshell prompt you want to modify.
2. Call <kbd>C-u M-x</kbd> `remove-text-properties-interactive`. (Note that the long command name does not hurt very much because of the available tab-completion in the minibuffer.)
3. Do your modifications on the prompt string.